# Explicitly deleted move constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, copy-constructor

Why this:

```
struct A
{
    A(int) {
        cout << "construct from int" << endl;
    }

    A(A&&) = delete;

    A(const A &) {
        cout << "copy constructor" << endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    A a = 0;
}
```

gives me an error:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘A::A(A&&)’
```

And why when I add such move constructor

```
A(A&&) {
    cout << "move constructor" << endl;
}
```

it compiles fine, but programm's output is just

```
construct from int
```

So as far as I understand, compiler asks for constructor but doesn't use it. Why? This makes no sense to me.

P.S. I assume that

```
A a = 0;
```

is equvalent of

```
A a = A(0);
```

but why neither move constructor nor move assignment operator is called?

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: This changed in C++17 (the deleted move constructor compiles now), but copy/move elision was always a thing before that.

Comment: I tried it on g++4.9, g++6.3 and on clang 5.0 all same. (-O0 -std=c++11)

Comment: Indeed, compiles on clang 5 with -std=c++17

Comment: And now for some unsolicited advice: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLinb2fgkHk&t=55m51s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard (12.8 Copying and moving class objects)

> 31 When certain criteria are met, an implementation is allowed to omit
>   the copy/move construction of a class object, even if the constructor
>   selected for the copy/move operation and/or the destructor for the
>   object have side effects. In such cases, the implementation treats the
>   source and target of the omitted copy/move operation as simply two
>   different ways of referring to the same object, and the destruction of
>   that object occurs at the later of the times when the two objects
>   would have been destroyed without the optimization.122 This elision of
>   copy/move operations, called copy elision, is permitted in the
>   following circumstances (which may be combined to eliminate multiple
>   copies):
>   ....
>   — when a temporary class object that has not been bound to a reference
>   (12.2) would be copied/moved to a class object with the same
>   cv-unqualified type, **the copy/move operation can be omitted by
>   constructing the temporary object directly into the target of the
>   omitted copy/move**

and

> 30 A program is ill-formed if the copy/move constructor or the
>   copy/move assignment operator for an object is implicitly odr-used and
>   the special member function is not accessible (Clause 11). [ Note:
>   Copying/moving one object into another using the copy/move constructor
>   or the copy/move assignment operator does not change the layout or
>   size of either object. —end note ]

Comment: I find it's very hard to understand the Standard, can you give some explaination or sample code ?

Comment: @HảiPhạmLê It is enough to read the bolded text. And a sample code is given in the question.